# How do i use AJAX in a given code to load images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
<style>
  .active {position:relative!important;}

    .animate {
      -webkit-transition:all .3s;
      -moz-transition:all .3s;
      -ms-transition:all .3s;
      -o-transition:all .3s;
      transition:all .3s
    }

    .box{
      height:200px;
      background-color:gray;
      border:1px solid black;
    }
    #test {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      position:relative;
      width:3805px;
    }
  }
  #div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5 {float: left;}

  #div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width:761px;
  }
  #div2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 761px;
    width:761px;
  }
  #div3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1522px;
    width:761px;
  }
  #div4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2283px;
    width:761px;
  }
  #div5 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3044px;
    width:761px;
  }
  #div6 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 3805px;
    width:761px;
  }
</style>
<div class="effect" id="test">
<div class="box" id="div1"><img src="http://shop.until.com.au/images/MosaicPlate-sm.jpg">DIV1</div>
<div class="box" id="div2"><img src="http://images.fnp.in/0/images/product/1_EgglessBlackforest_s.jpg">DIV2</div>
<div class="box" id="div3"><img src="http://1.imimg.com/data1/D/S/MY-991522/corporate-gifts-250x250.jpg">DIV3</div>
<div class="box" id="div4"><img src="http://cdn.appstorm.net/web.appstorm.net/files/2011/12/Gift_poll1.png">DIV4</div>
<div class="box" id="div5"><img src="http://content.modaco.net/dropzone/presenticon.png">DIV5</div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="a1">1</button>
<button type="button" class="a2">2</button>
<button type="button" class="a3">3</button>
<button type="button" class="a4">4</button>
<button type="button" class="a5">5</button>

<script>
  $("document").ready(function(){
    $(".a1").click(function(){
      $(".box").removeClass( "active" );
      $("#div1").addClass( "active" );
      $("#test").css({"-webkit-transform":"translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1)"});
      $("#test").addClass( "animate" );
    });
  $(".a2").click(function(){
      $(".box").removeClass( "active" );
      $("#div2").addClass( "active" );
      $("#test").css({"-webkit-transform":"translate3d(-20%, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1)"});
      $("#test").addClass( "animate" );
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Q1:**
In above code how do I load image using AJAX when clicking on button "1" and not loading others images.

**Q2:**
Above Jquery script is for button "1" and "2" to display `div`. same thing can be done for remain button to show other `div`s but is there any way like iterating `div`. Basically i dont want to repeat same code for all button.

http://jsfiddle.net/5f6Wg/167/

Answer (score 1):

Here is tweak:

**jQuery Code:**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('[class^="a"]').filter(function () {
        return this.className.match(/\d+$/);
    }).click(function () {
        var i = ($(this).index() - 1);
        $(".box").removeClass("active");
        $("#div" + i).addClass("active");
        $("#test").css({
            "-webkit-transform" : "translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1)"
        });
        $("#test").addClass("animate");
    });
});
```

**Code Explain:**

```
$('[class^="a"]')
```

will select all elements who's have class name starting with `'a'`
Then we have to filter elements who's class end with number

```
.filter(function () {
    return this.className.match(/\d+$/);
})
```

Now, our desire elements select and we can do anything with jQuery event :)

Here is working **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/j782V/)**

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: [Load Image On Click With AJAX (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102078/load-image-on-click-with-ajax-jquery)

You can adopt the given answer

```
$(function(){
   $("#imgUser").load("images/testimg.jpg");  
});
```

just use the second line in your click handler.

Edit: to Q2:

If you change the classes of the buttons from aX to X you could use a function like

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var x = $(this).attr('class');
  $(".box").removeClass( "active" );
  $("#div"+x).addClass( "active" );
  $("#test").css({"-webkit-transform":"translate3d(-20%, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1)"});
  $("#test").addClass( "animate" );
});
```